# Alternative to Google Adsense

Tags: google-adsense, advertising

I have a web dev blog which averages ~100 uniques per day, on which I have a few ads here and there via Google Adsense.

These ads generate around £5 per month for me. While I'm not out to make money, it would be nice to be able to cover my hosting and domain costs.

Can someone recommend a good alternative to Google Ads which could bring in a little more? If so, could you also detail your experience with as much info as possible, please?

Again, I'm not looking to make money off my blog but if I have ads on there, I may as well get the most out of them and if I can turn that £5 a month into £10 a month, it's a good start.

I'm very naive to the world of online ads and any search on the topic returns clearly promoted posts with impossibly high numbers.

Comment: I think you mean adsense alternative and not adwords, the problem here is the low volume of hits per a day and not the ad engine your using. Google Adsense has very competitive margins and your find it hard to beat, my advice would be on increasing traffic by posting more often, use of social media, and ensuring what you post is very hi-quality. I'm using comment because I believe this question will be closed because its duplicate, while I appreciate your question may be unique in terms of making £5 into £10 fundamentally your asking for a Adsense alternative which has been asked before.

Comment: You are correct, I do mean adsense. Long day :) I have updated my post. Thanks for the response

Comment: Adsense is your best deal. You won't get anything better than adsense in terms of CPC as well as CTR.